# Error Installing Nodejs on OSX Maverick

Tags: node.js, macos, osx-mavericks

Last month, I used to install new nodejs in my laptop and it's fine, but now there is error with the installation.
I'm using the .pkg file which latest nodejs (v 0.10.32)

The error said :

"There were errors with the installation. You may want to try i"

"The installation failed"

"The Installer could not install the software."

"The Installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install"

Is there is solution with this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [brew](http://brew.sh/) its a packet manager for OSX.

Installing brew is pretty easy:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After installing it you can simply do:

```
brew install nodejs
```

Which will install the newest version from source.

```
==> Downloading http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.32/node-v0.10.32.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32 --without-npm
==> make install
```